# Intensity of sound signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

Hi folks I got stuck trying to find the intensity of sound signal. I searched a lot but didn't get any good answers or help. I will be very thankful if anyone could guide me about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't give the down vote, just the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just calculate the [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) value of the signal, e.g. if your samples are in X:

```
intensity_RMS = sqrt(sum(X.*X)/length(X));
```